# Remove carriage returns in text column during MySQL query in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting a text column in a MySQL query for export to a csv file in a PHP script.  It turns out the text column has carriage returns which is causing an issue with import on the other end.

How do I remove carriage returns while making the query and just present the text?  Here is my current query:

```
SELECT marketing_remarks AS MarketingRemarks WHERE column = "blah"
```

Comment: Seems Google has the answer... https://www.google.co.uk/#q=php%20remove%20carriage%20return%20line%20feed - or is there a more specific problem you have?

Comment: The problem is not the select, the problem is that I need to remove the carriage returns in the result.

Comment: @ChrisW ...I don't see a SQL solution here, only PHP...I tried Google ;-)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do it in PHP?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep it in a single MySQL statement for ease of administration. Cleaner code, I only want PHP where I absolutely have to (creation of the export file etc.).  If it concerns data processing, I figure it is better to keep that within the SQL and PHP for file operations.

Comment: Why not just remove the carriage returns on insert? (Or if it's just the existing data, remove them from there?)

Comment: Well, I must say, I do agree with keeping all logic together :) [I just thought I'd give the alternative anyway!]

Comment: I don't have that option @JohnV. .. I only control the select, not the insert.  Thanks Chris, normally would not matter but the SQL is so much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(marketing_remarks, '\r', '') AS MarketingRemarks WHERE column = "blah"
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it in the query (as per Fredd's answer), or in the PHP:

```
str_replace("\r", '', $result); // remove carriage returns
```

there will be factors which will determine which is the best approach for you